# Problems running integration test EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, ejb

Code from Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1 chapter 4. If you need more code or information just ask!

```
public class SimpleCalculatorIntegrationTest {

    private static SimpleCalculatorBean calc;
    private static Context namingContext;
    private static final String JNDI_NAME_CALC = "java:global/SimpleCalculatorEJB/SimpleCalculatorBean";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void obtainProxyReferences() throws NamingException {
        namingContext = new InitialContext();

        calc = (SimpleCalculatorBean) namingContext.lookup(JNDI_NAME_CALC);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddition() {

        int expectedSum = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4; // 10

        assertEquals(expectedSum, calc.add(1, 2, 3, 4));
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

> 11.okt.2011 20:41:28 com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl
>   findDerbyClient INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc
>   driver will not be available by default. java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Orb initialization erorr  at
>   org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:180)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:365)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:372)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:402)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:347)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:504)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)  at
>   no.breakpoint.ejbbook.calculator.test.SimpleCalculatorIntegrationTest.obtainProxyReferences(SimpleCalculatorIntegrationTest.java:24)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:152)
>     ... 23 more

Comment: Are you executing the test in the container (i.e. using Arquillian?).
If you're running outside of the container be sure that you're not using a local or no-interface EJB view as you're trying to reach it from another JVM.

Comment: @PedroKowalski Do you have 5 minutes to come on the Java chat? I really would appriciate some help so I can move on to the next chapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to sum up our chat conversation for other interested users:

You can write tests that works on your EJB's in two ways:

1. Testing **outside-of-the-container**. It means that your tests run as a different application on different JVM. In this case you need to use the **Remote** interface EJB view and JNDI to locate your EJB. The JNDI coordinates are construct as written in [EJB 3.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/) regarding portable JNDI syntax (p. 81). In case of Glassfish you just need to:

   - add the remote interface to your classpath (to be able to use it),
   - add the gf-client.jar to your classpath.

Then you will be able to locate your EJB's remote interface by invoking code somewhat similar to this:

```
public class Main {

    private static final String JNDI = 
                    "java:global/yourApp/YourEJBBean!com.test.YourEJBBeanRemote";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();

        YourEJBBeanRemote sr = (YourEJBBeanRemote)ctx.lookup(JNDI);

        // Invoke some method on 'sr'
    }
}
```

2.  Testing **inside-of-the-container**. It means that your tests are executed within the container and, very likely, together with your application. This allows you to use dependency injection, EntityManagers, local/no-interface EJB's view and so on. With [JBoss Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian), you write your tests just assuming that all the services are provided for you.

The EJB 3.1 new no-interface view is just like local view, so it cannot be used for clients residing outside of the application.